# Why does the terminal show different output when I'm connected as the same user running the same command?

Tags: bash, terminal

I SSH'd to a Linux machine using the same user and ran the same command as shown below, but the output is different. I'm relatively new to Linux, so I would appreciate an explanation for what I'm seeing.

As you can see, I don't see as many columns of data through my PuTTY session as through my PowerShell session.

[image]

Comment: What command is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to how wide your terminal is:

```
const CONDENSED_MODE = (process.stdout.columns || 300) < 120
```

[`pm2/lib/API/UX/pm2-ls.js:12`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/6e9bb1ee01c0132c76511b605968187072e1a746/lib/API/UX/pm2-ls.js#L12)

Answer (score 0):

Each terminal has a number of rows/columns. Depending on that size (which in turns depends on the window and font size) certain programs will adapt their output, so that it fits.

You can run `tput cols` and `tput lines` to check how big each terminal is. If they are the same size, you *should* get the same output.